# change the character that separates a url (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am obtaining the url with route.queryParams.subscribe and to separate the parameters I do it with Object.keys(params) where the latter separates them when it finds the "&". My question is, can I modify that separator, where I separate it when I find the character "$" for example and not the "&"?

The short code:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.keys = Object.keys(params);

}
```

```
Example this url www.hi.com?v%2BRSC60dbdNliPmWIS8mbw%3D%3D=&uHW0Oj81Fug5ifNoPI4rGSpH5uaejSqrADBFSQhRU4fKQF3oIAXWRqtpv3TNsi3c7GDgva1P%2FozKCMFkd%2FDQEKqM1DBhmnV05psQ1n913EM5NjRNK53sEo60YxgVGky1bV%2BPB2C%2F1cG44b%2FrQPNmns7jWgQmWopQvO%2FCzWCD8o12HNQoINRzi%2FWsg9OUhoNncPl%2BU8OsJWUbKutTpW%2FiLHa4IQRvlSG59iyj6HVC2hwXwZnXVXGfDDTX3bP4Am4HQlO61CsaidcoF6mEVGSpLg%3D%3D=
```

when you go through the code above it looks like this, where "&" is the separator

```
0 : v%2BRSC60dbdNliPmWIS8mbw%3D%3D=

&

1: uHW0Oj81Fug5ifNoPI4rGSpH5uaejSqrADBFSQhRU4fKQF3oIAXWRqtpv3TNsi3c7GDgva1P%2FozKCMFkd%2FDQEKqM1DBhmnV05psQ1n913EM5NjRNK53sEo60YxgVGky1bV%2BPB2C%2F1cG44b%2FrQPNmns7jWgQmWopQvO%2FCzWCD8o12HNQoINRzi%2FWsg9OUhoNncPl%2BU8OsJWUbKutTpW%2FiLHa4IQRvlSG59iyj6HVC2hwXwZnXVXGfDDTX3bP4Am4HQlO61CsaidcoF6mEVGSpLg%3D%3D=
```

So, I want to know if there is a way to modify the separator character, for example instead of "&" they pass me the url with the character "$" for example and that I separate it in the same way.

This is Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case it is useful for you, you can use this:

in the imports

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

in your code

```
const id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id"));
```

lets suppouse your route is this one:
http://localhost:4200/identification/:id

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple do:

```
string.split("any character you want")
```

It will return list of array of the string splitted at `"any character you want"`.
Or find the index using:

```
string.indexOf("any character you want")
```

Then splice the string accoordingly. You can even loop the string and return the index using `array.forEach` and `splice` it at that position.

Comment: yes, I thought about it but it changes the special characters to hexadecimal, for example the "=" changes them to "3D"